# Missing headers in uploadTask allHeaderFields. Doesn't include custom headers from Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Tags: ios, swift, cors

My server is using CORS. When a user logs in successfully, the response includes the headers: `access-token, uid, client`

The server response headers include: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:access-token, uid, client`

However, when I get a successful response from an uploadTask, and access `allHeaderFields` these keys/values are missing.

What do I need to do to access these headers?

Thanks!

EDIT Adding client code that works just fine now:

```
func postReq(url: URL) -> URLRequest{
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

    return request
}

func login(){
        let url:URL = baseEndpoint.appendingPathComponent(Endpoints.login.rawValue)
        let request: URLRequest = postReq(url: url)
        let body: [String : String] = ["email" : "test@test.com", "password": "loremipsum"]

        let bodyData:Data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)

        uploadTask = defaultSession.uploadTask(with: request, from: bodyData, completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                let headers =  (response as! HTTPURLResponse).allHeaderFields

            }
        })
        uploadTask?.resume()

    }
```

ANNNND Fixed my problem.  There wasn't an issue, I was just missing the correct content type. Facepalm.

Comment: You have more luck getting answer if you post some version of your client code or at least clearly indicate what runtime your client code is running in. `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` only affects the behavior for browser engines, so is this something you’re trying to do from frontend JavaScript script code running in iOS Safari? Or instead in Swift code? If it actually is Swift code, then `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is irrelevant.

Comment: What a bonehead move. Turned out that i was just missing the correct content type in my request. Groan. @sideshowbarker made me take another look at it. Thank you!